# How to do a selection inside a Jquery autocomplete dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to do a selection field inside a Jquery autocompletion dialog. While this html element is visible the dialog prevents the user from clicking on it. Any tips as to how I can override the default behaviour for single elements?

Alternatively is it possible to get something like the Menu widget to work inside of an autocomplete field so that I could so multi layered selections?

This is a code sniplet of what I try to do:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>

    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
        _create: function() {
            this._super();
            this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
        },
        _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label +"</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        },
        _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
            var that = this,
            currentCategory = "";
            ul.prepend('Please Select <select name="number" id="number"> <option>1</option> <option selected="selected">2</option> <option>3</option> </select>');
            $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                var li;
                if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                    ul.append( "<br><li class='ui-autocomplete-category'><b>" + item.category + "</b></li>" );
                    currentCategory = item.category;
                }
                li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
                if ( item.category ) {
                    li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $( function()
    {   var availableTags = [{label:"Apple",category:"Red"},{label:"Strawberry",category:"Red"},{label:"Coconut",category:"Brown"},];
        $( "#tags" ).catcomplete(
        {   source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
Fruits: <input id="tags">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you use select2 ?

Comment: http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/examples.html ... Go and learn ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Select2 kinda works (with some graphic artefacts). However, once you click on any element on that select it closes the autocomplete which I don't want. The workflow would be to be able to select one option and over that the regular selection in the autocomplete.